# How to select value of drop down list with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have just started my first project with python and already spend hours searching for a solution, but couldn't find anything.

I would like to fill out a website, by selecting values from drop-down list. My problem is that the values of these lists are not hard coded like in the solutions I found in this forum.

I have inspected the website and made three screenshots (before clicking, when clicking and after selecting an item)

[before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33tUd.png)

[by cklicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QioJ.png)

[after selecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l73MA.png)

I was able to open the drop-down-list and read all values of the list, but not able to select one of them

```
css = 'body > main > section > section > div.ut-navigation-container-view--content > div > div.ut-pinned-list-container.ut-content-container > div > div.ut-pinned-list > div.ut-item-search-view > div:nth-child(2)'
iElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css)
SpanVariableValue = iElement.text
#prints selected value or default 
print (SpanVariableValue )

iElement.click()
SpanVariableValue = iElement.text
#prints all elemets of drop-down
print (SpanVariableValue)

#drop-down doesn't work after the following code 
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'SILVER'", iElement)
```

Can anybody help me with my problem?

Cheers,
Andi

Edit: Sorry, I made a mistake when adding the screenshots in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already attempted this when looking through the Selenium documentation, you could give the following a try:

```
Selenium.click()
```

An example command would look something like this:

```
element = driver.find_element :xpath, '//input[@name="q"]'
element.click()
```

You can just set the element xpath to be the elements of the drop down, then Selenium would be able to click the options you want.

Comment: yes I checked the documentation and I already found a lot of tips like your, but my problem is that my xpath looks completly different
/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]